# jQuery inArray not picking up value - clearly in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
console.log(response.key);
console.log(answersNeedToBeBoolean);
console.log($.inArray(response.key, answersNeedToBeBoolean));
```

Output in console:

```
177
[8, 177, 179, 181]
-1
```

These seems pretty cut and dry to me. Clearly 177 is in the array. How on earth could it not find it?

Comment: can you try `console.log(jQuery.isArray(answersNeedToBeBoolean))`

Comment: It works if the values are as you've stated. There's something more to it than that.

Comment: One reason could be `answersNeedToBeBoolean` is an array of int values where as `response.key` is a string so try `console.log($.inArray(+response.key, answersNeedToBeBoolean));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if `response.key` is a string `'177'` output would be `-1`

```
177
[8, 177, 179, 181]
-1
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/vofa0mcn/)**

If its an integer `177` output would be 1.

Use `JSON.parse()` or `parseInt()`, as you have an integer array.

```
$.inArray(JSON.parse(response.key), answersNeedToBeBoolean)
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/vofa0mcn/1/)**

Comment: Thanks - this was the problem.